# Http 404 when I try to invoke a method in webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services, .net-4.0, asmx

I have created in an existed project a simple HelloWorld `webservice` with a `HelloWorld` method

The method HelloWorld is listed when I call this url

I can click on the method and display the page of the following url:

```
local/WebService.asmx?op=HelloWorld
```

The problem is when I try to invoke the method on this page

the result is a `http 404 page`

```
local/WebService.asmx/HelloWorld/index.aspx is the url that can not be found
```

I found some answers on `stackoverflow`
and try to implement a rule like this but it does not work

```
routes.Ignore("{*x}", new { x = @".*\.asmx(/.*)?" });
```

Comment: That's the problem, the button invoke on the page of the method try to open this url (no index.aspx) local/WebService.asmx/HelloWorld/

Comment: That's the problem, the button invoke on the page of the method try to open this url (no index.aspx) local/WebService.asmx/HelloWorld/ but try to open index.asp I have read the doc and think it is a problem whith .net4.0 , may be I have to add a rule with .asmx/* in web.config but it does not work